# error in awscli call doesnt send to logfile

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

we have to check for the status of instance and iam trying to capture if any error to logfile. logfile has instance inforamtion but the error is not being writen to logfile below is code let me know what needs to be corrected

```
function wait-for-status {
    instance=$1
    target_status=$2
    status=unknown
    while [[ "$status" != "$target_status" ]]; do
        status=`aws rds describe-db-instances \
            --db-instance-identifier $instance | head -n 1 \
            | awk -F \  '{print $10}'` >> ${log_file} 2>&1
        sleep 30
    echo $status >> ${log_file}
    done
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `${log_file}`? That is a syntax for executing the command inside the braces. Why not just use `>> /path/log_file`?

Comment: I have some other functions in the same script using varible there it's not issue having variable there even if I provide complete path it doesn't send the error to logs

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using all that `head`/`awk` stuff, if you want a value out of the CLI, you should use the `--query` parameter. For example:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier xxx --query 'DBInstances[*].DBInstanceStatus'
```

See: [Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Also, if your goal is to wait until an Amazon RDS instance is available, then you should use [db-instance-available — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html):

```
aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier xxx
```